# Toggle permission to use shell escape in document itself

Tags: shell-escape

Permitting LaTeX to execute shell code (aka -enable-write-18) is dangerous.  But I sometimes need it due to dot2texi.  So in my IDE (which in my case is WinEdt) I manually switch it on when I work with dot2texi, and switch it off when when I do not longer work with dot2texi AND (important) do not forget it (weak spot).  I vaguely recall that switching on shell escapes can be done as per document.  That would be nice.  Does anyone remember how?

Comment: Have you thought about using [`arara`](http://www.ctan.org/tex-archive/support/arara/)?

Comment: You could use `arara` with the directive `% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }`.

Comment: By coincide or not, I stumbled upon arara some half hour ago, before asking my question.  I admit it is a solution, and I am glad with it, but arara seems like a heavy solution for such a simple operation?

Comment: There is not/should not be a solution at TeX macro level. Otherwise it would be easy for malicious code to turn on shell escape.

Comment: @cmhughes Done.

Answer (score 3):

The tool [`arara`](https://github.com/cereda/arara) is a great piece of software by our fellow duck-loving StackExchanger [Paulo Cereda](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/3094/paulo-cereda). It works somewhat like the TeXworks magic comments (see below) in that sense, that you can control the sequence of your typesetting process.

For example, to get the citation right, you normally need to run `latex` to generate the `aux`-file, then `bibtex` to generate the `bbl`-file, then again `latex` to include the `bbl`-file and to regenerate the `aux`-file with now right labels, and then a third time `latex` to get your references right. Phew!

Because this is a lot of typing exercise in your terminal, or a lot of keystrokes in your editor, there is `arara`. You just insert comments right in the first lines of your file, à la

```
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex
% arara: pdflatex
```

and then run `arara` on that file, e.g. `arara example.tex`. Hopefully you then see

```
  __ _ _ __ __ _ _ __ __ _ 
 / _` | '__/ _` | '__/ _` |
| (_| | | | (_| | | | (_| |
 \__,_|_|  \__,_|_|  \__,_|

Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running BibTeX... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
Running PDFLaTeX... SUCCESS
```

You can also add further options to the single tasks, like shell escape:

```
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: bibtex
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
% arara: pdflatex: { shell: yes }
```

For more info read the magnificent documentation, or see this tutorial on texdev.net: http://www.texdev.net/2012/04/24/arara-making-latex-files-your-way/

---

With TeXworks magic comments you can set typesetting engine, encoding, etc. Here an example:

```
% !TeX program = LuaLaTeX
% !TeX encoding = UTF-8
% !TeX root = example.tex
% !TeX spellcheck = en_GB
```

Comment: I believe that MiKTeX's implementation can specify options in the first input line.

Comment: @egreg I never used MikTeX. If want to write some lines about this, feel free to edit.

Comment: I've never used it either. I believe to have seen something like that.

Comment: @egreg Some googling revealed, that `%& --enable-write18` as the first line should work, but I can't test it. From: http://docs.miktex.org/manual/tex.html